# Help with dropping shadow

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Can you please help me to understand where shadow will go under this computer? I need it to look like it is standing on the table[image]

Comment: Decide where you think the light is coming from, the shadow will lie in the opposite direction.

Comment: Thank you, I guess according to keyboard lights, it should go like a square on side of computer, but I'm not sure

Comment: Try it and see if it look natural

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The computer seems to be well lit from every direction. The light comes from large surfaces. The desk below it is assumed to be white, I guess.

In the next screenshot the white is deleted from the computer image layer partially to make some room for the shadow. There's inserted a separate white background for later needs:

[image]

A shadow is possible if the amount of the light  to the connector end of the computer is reduced. I inserted a curves layer to do it.

[image]

The layer mask (to limit the area of the light reduction) is painted manually by making at first a selection with Polygonal Lasso. The mask is faded smoothly at the curved corners. The curve itself will be adjusted better later.

A new layer is inserted and a big enough black splash is painted. It will be refined later to small and subtle enough shadow:

[image]

The black splash layer is moved between the computer layer and the background. It's scaled smaller, rotated a little and blurred with Gaussian Blur effect. The layer opacity is reduced and the curve in the adjustment layer is tweaked a little to make the lights to seem to have some accordance:

[image]

I wouldn't insert more shadow because the distant background seems to be a strong light, as you see from the reflection on the keyboard.

Off-topic, but I'm sure it would look more like being on a desk if there was one.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I drew two levels of shadows.

The black one is the main one showing the computer sitting on the table.

The gray one is to make it more compatible with the layers floating in front of it.

[image]

You need to mask the computer (I did not) and blur the shadows.

[image]

My transition between the two on my test is very sloppy. Play with the blurs.

---

The lines should be parallel or based on the angles of the computer (red lines)

In reality, your shadows should extend further back of the computer, around green lines, but this creates additional problems in making them "accurate". For example, there should be a fall-off with the distances.

Here is a link to show these additional problems with the directions and levels for the blurs. [How to create a realistic shadow like in this image below? Super Realistic one](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/103450/how-to-create-a-realistic-shadow-like-in-this-image-below-super-realistic-one/161377#161377)

[image]

But shadows that far are not necessary. The image has an "illustration" look that justifies not being accurate.

Comment: Thank you so much! Very helpful!

Comment: Welcome to the website. One feature of the website is that if the answer is useful or informative, you upvote it. And if it solves your issue, you mark it as solved.